# How to get product by tag using Woocommerce API Client

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get products from woocommerce using API REST Client as following :

```
 $args = array(
            'filter[limit]' => 3,
            'filter[tags]' => 'today',
            'filter[orderby]' => 'date',
            'filter[order]' => 'DESC'
            );


return $this->client->products->get('', $args);
```

I got list of all prods, but I need only the ones with the tag 'todays'

Thanks.

Comment: In your code the tag is "toady" not "todays". Could be you have a typo?

Comment: May be because categories and tags are arrays, it will not work as it…

Comment: Todays is the tag, i wrote today is order to get an empty return, but all I got is the list of all products. Also triend to make it an array, didn't work !

Comment: did you find a solution?